# Distinguishing between same exception by where it was called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an unavoidable situation that looks like this (simplified):

```
FUNCTION_TO_CALL = y # can be either y or z
def x(*args, **kargs):
  FUNCTION_TO_CALL(args, kargs)

def y(foo, bar=None):
  if foo == bar: # actually not this stupid
    raise TypeError()
  else:
    pass

def z(foo, bar, baz=None):
  pass
```

Horribly ugly, I know. :(

But, at any rate, I need to be able to distinguish between a TypeError being raised in `y` because `*args` doesn't have anything in it or having too much in it (thus not having enough arguments or too many)/bad `kwargs` or because `foo == bar`.

In the actually setting, there are many more functions that can be called than two, not all of which have the code open to them.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Billenstein's comment on Keith Morrow's answer is the right way to do this. But alternatively, if for some bizarre reason you can't even do that, you could also look at the `inspect` module.

```
try: ugly()
except TypeError as e:
    stack = inspect.stack()
    [...look at the stack...]
```

[Info about the inspect module.](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack)

To elaborate on the "wrapping" question: assuming you have control over what functions are available to be assigned to `FUNCTION_TO_CALL`, create `y_better`

```
def y_better(foo, bar=None):
    try: y(foo, bar)
    except TypeError:
        if foo == bar: # detect foobar condition
            raise FoobarError()
        else:          # not foobar, so re-raise the exception
            raise
```

This means foo == bar is being tested twice, but given your restrictions, I don't see a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could always make your own exceptions subclassing TypeError, and use them individually.

```
class TooManyArgumentsError(TypeError):
    pass
class EqualityError(TypeError):
    pass
```

Comment: No, I can't—the functions that raise `TypeError` are written in code I can't modify.

Comment: So wrap the functions you can't modify, catch TypeError and raise a different exception...

Comment: How would I wrap the function?

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom exception:

class yTypeError(TypeError):
       pass

then raise this in y() and only in y()